# Как локализировать breadcrumps с английского на русский?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть вот такой react компонент

```
const Breadcrumbsss = () => {

    const location = useLocation()

    let currentLink = ''

    const crumbs = location.pathname.split('/')
        .filter(crumb => crumb !== '')
        .map(crumb => {
            currentLink += `/${crumb}`

            return (
                <div className="crumb" key={crumb}>
                    <Link to={currentLink}>{crumb}</Link>
                </div>
            )
        })


    return (
        <Breadcrumbs className="breadcrumbs"
                     separator="⯈"
                     aria-label="breadcrumb"
                     sx={{fontSize: "12px", background: "#fff", position:"static"}}>

            {crumbs}
        </Breadcrumbs>
    );
};

export default Breadcrumbsss;
```

Когда захожу, например, по такому url'у - http://localhost:3000/spravochnik/groupsTable
то, breadcrumbs выглядит так ~
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно подменить на русский язык? Например, вместо spravochnik написать на русском Справочник.
Breadcrumbs компонент берется из MUI.